# What is the purpose of GETting this external file?

Tags: http, firefox

A website I am visiting occasionally makes XHR requests to `http://detectportal.firefox.com/success.txt` which is a `text/plain` resource whose body contains the text `success`.

I am unable to figure out what the purpose of this HTTP request might be.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is used by Firefox when detecting whether it is using a captive portal.

A captive portal is a Web page that the user of a public-access network is obliged to view and interact with before access is granted.

Captive portals are typically used by business centers, airports, hotel lobbies, coffee shops, and other venues that offer free Wi-Fi hot spots for Internet users.

http://searchmobilecomputing.techtarget.com/definition/captive-portal

Comment: So what you are proposing is that when the browser trying to access the website is connected through such a coffee shop, the request to ...detectportal... does not return `success` and thus the browser (the javascript) will do something different?

Comment: No idea how it is used.

Comment: The website isn't trying to access that url. Your browser's built-in mechanisms are doing that. And if it doesn't return `success`, Firefox will show an alert notification with a link to load the captive portal (so you can accept the terms or login to the filtered wifi connection).

Answer (score 4):

> Captive portals are generally found at public wi-fi hot-sports, 
>   Starbucks, Airports.
>
> Firefox uses this to detect if it's trapped in a 
>   captive portal (success.txt not found) or can really access the internet 
>   (success.txt found). In other words it's just Firefox checking for 
>   a proxied environment.
>
> If you put that URL into your hosts file. Firefox may decide that you 
>   are caught in a fake wi-fi hotspot.

Source: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mozilla.support.firefox/TJgV_uODg_I/uEe30_njBAAJ

Answer (score 2):

To disable this:

1. Enter `about:config` into your location bar. Accept the risk.
2. Locate and set `network.captive-portal-service` to `false`

Source: https://www.blackhillsinfosec.com/towards-quieter-firefox/